# Leaving just the first column in the csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to leave just the first column of a csv file. But it seems not to be working for me and can not find the working solution.

```
def leavethefirstcolumn(filename):
    with open(filename) as f, open('out.csv', "w") as out:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            out.write(row[0])
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? Are you trying to just keep the first column of a CSV, that is remove all the other columns but the first ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you give an example of the csv? When you saying that it is not working, what do you mean (could you give an expected output and obtained output)?

Comment: what is the file in csv.reader(file)

Comment: is filename a text file with multiple rows?

Comment: Sorry vsrukshan, it was supposed to be f instead of file and Jean-Louis Mbaka already solved my problem, big thanks.

Comment: happy to see that you sloved the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import csv

def leavethefirstcolumn(filename):
  with open(filename) as file, open('out.csv', "w") as out:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
      out.write(row[0] + "\n")

# example of using the function
leavethefirstcolumn("in.csv")
```

1. You are calling `csv.reader(file)` while on the previous line, you wrote `with open(filename) as f` instead of `with open(filename) as file`.
2. Also when you are writing to `out`, you should add a new line
   character '\n'